# mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource

Tags: php, sql-server

I am getting the above error using PHP trying to update an MS SQL server. Any idea what may be happening here? I am using a stored procedure as the basis of the update. I can successfully execute the sproc against the SQL server away from the PHP application.

Any advice/help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you post a code example it would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 3):

mssql_fetch_array() should be used for SELECT commands, you won't get anything out of UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE commands.

You can also pass a parameter to the resource by calling `mssql_fetch_array($connection)` assuming `$connection` is a valid connection to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Always test the return value of mssql_query(). If it's ===false [mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/mssql_get_last_message) can tell you why the query failed.

```
$query = 'SELECT x,y,z FROM [foo].[bar].[thingeling]';
$result = @mssql_query($query, $conn);
if(!$result) {
  die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

For debugging purposes you might want to set [mssql_min_message_severity](http://php.net/mssql_min_message_severity) and [mssql_min_error_severity](http://php.net/mssql_min_error_severity) to more "talkative" values.